# SharePoint 2010 Document Set's Welcome Page Gives 404 Error

Tags: document-set

I have an OOTB site and document library. I added the document set content type to the library without any errors. I created a new document set, added the attributes and clicked OK. It went directly to a 404 page.

I went back to the document library home page, refreshed and the new document set record was displayed. I was able to view and edit properties.

=====

1) If I navigate to:

```
http://mySP/sites/mySPSite/_layouts/DocSetHome.aspx?id=/corpaffair/DRMSProjects/TEST01/TEST_A
```

I get the 404 error

=====

2) If I navigate to:

```
http://mySP/sites/mySPSite/_layouts/DocSetHome.aspx
```

I get a System.NullReferenceException error which makes sense since I removed the id attribute

=====

**Question**

How do I debug a 404 error for a Document Set's Welcome Page?

Comment: can not deactivate - get Cannot deactivate the feature because the Document Set content type is in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by deactivating and activating the site collection feature **Document Sets**.